# How to display two arrays in two different cells in UITableView using swift3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to display two arrays in two different cells in a table view but it doesn't works , can any one help me to solve this problem , I am using Xcode8 and Swift3 , and this is my TableView code .

this is how I want to display the two arrays :

row1 = aaa

row2 = 11111

row3 = bbb

row4 = 2222

row5 = cccc

row6 = 3333

row7 = ddd

row8 = eee

row9 = fff

My code :

```
 import UIKit

 class _CellsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var array1 = [String]()
var array2 = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    array1 = ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff"]

    array2 = ["11111","22222","33333"]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {



        return array1.count + array2.count


}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

   cell.textLabel?.text = array1[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }
    else {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = array2[indexPath.row]

    return cell

    }

 }


 }
```

Comment: what the problem u faced

Comment: fatal error: Index out of range , thats the error.

Comment: Why the heck do you think `if indexPath.row == 0` would do this? Seems a basic programming issue.

Comment: Ok, would you show me how to solve it .

Comment: ya surely you get , bz if you are using `if indexPath.row == 0 {` , it is the one index and at the same time your array count is 9 but you load different  ok simple this is `if indexPath.row == 0 {` or `if indexPath.section == 0 {`

Comment: @ZaidMustafa How much do you pay me to do your work? You're a programmer right? First try something reasonable yourself, then ask others.

Comment: first of all a class starts with a upper case letter, so please remove the _ from `CellsTableViewController`. ^^ it hurts my eyes. second, are you sure you want to implement a custom tableViewController? or are you just planning to use a tableView in your viewControlller?

Comment: You got the error because you set the number of rows array1 and array2 total count but if you look at cellforrow function you only use array1 for the first line of tableview. Other lines will be populated by array2 until array2 elements end. So basically you say there will be 9 number of rows but you only populate it until your array2 elements end which is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you need to do this. But you code should be:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var index = indexPath.row/2;

    if(index<array1.count %% index<array2.count)
    {
        if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0){
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = array1[index]
            return cell
        }
        else {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = array2[index]
            return cell
        }
    }
    else {
        var isFirst
        if(index>=array1.count)
        {
            index = indexPath.row - array1.count;
            isFirst = false
        }else
        {
            index = indexPath.row - array2.count;
            isFirst = true
        }
        if(isFirst)
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = array1[index]
            return cell
        }else
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = array2[index]
            return cell
        }
    }

 }
```

But I don't test this code.

Answer (score 3):

make a single array with combination of two and then reload table. See the following code,

```
let array1 = ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff"]
let array2 = ["11111","22222","33333"]
var arrayAllItems = [String]()
for i in 0..<max(array1.count, array2.count){
    if array1.count > i{
        arrayAllItems.append(array1[i])
    }
    if array2.count > i{
        arrayAllItems.append(array2[i])
    }
}
```

Reload table with array `arrayAllItems`

Comment: this is much better and cleaner then the accepted answer.